# Google improved search box within the search results not working

Tags: schema.org, google-rich-snippets, search-form

[image: Google displays a search box for the first result.]

I [follow Google’s tutorial](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2014/09/improved-sitelinks-search-box.html) for improved search box within the search results just like above screenshot.

I added this code in my front sitepage:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
   "@context": "http://schema.org",
   "@type": "WebSite",
   "url": "https://www.xxx.com/",
   "potentialAction": {
   "@type": "SearchAction",
      "target": "https://www.xxx.com/search/site/{keys}",
      "query-input": "required name=keys"
    }
 }

 </script>
```

Am I doing something wrong? My site uses Drupal 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks correct (assuming that `/search/site/strawberry` successfully searches for "strawberry").

Note that Google is not displaying the [Sitelinks Search Box](http://wayback.archive.org/web/20140906020658/https://developers.google.com/webmasters/richsnippets/sitelinkssearch) for all sites/queries:

> **Search box not displaying?** The sitelinks search box appears only for navigational queries and when relevant for users. Google algorithms use a variety of factors to determine when the box appears, including the information on the site and different types of navigational queries from Search users.

Edit: 2017-05-09 [Updated Sitelinks Search Box Information and URL](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/sitelinks-searchbox)